# Is HDFS required to use with MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs

We're exploring the use of MR to parallelize long-running processes. All of our data currently resides in RDBMS. We understand that HDFS is the underlying file-based data storage for MR, but were not sure of the following:

- Do we have to move all RDBMS data to HDFS to use MR?
- Is such a move permanent or temporary only for the life of the MR process?
- Can we use MR for its parallel features while jobs still acces data from traditional sources (not HDFS)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to move all RDBMS data to HDFS to use MR. Let's take a look at how Sqoop load data from RDBMS to HBase/HDFS.

Sqoop will load data by MapReduce with the help of  `[DBInputFormat]`[1](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html) (which is [a connector that allows Hadoop MapReduce programs to read rows from SQL databases](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/06/introducing-sqoop/)).

Comment: MR jobs use Sqoop to read data from RDBMS during processing? I thought Sqoop loads data into HDFS before MR processing?

Comment: The data load of Sqoop process itself is MR

Comment: I'm wondering if pre-loading data with sqoop is counter-productive to the batch process I want to parallelize. I have to sell MR to my team; pre-loading data just to run parallel jobs over it erodes the roi and value of doing MR in the first place. There is a cost to using Sqoop, right?

Comment: Preload data with sqoop to hdfs and then do MR is one option. But you could make use of some modules of Sqoop such as the DBInputFormat to directly design MR on top of data in RDBMS. Put it another way, Sqoop is used to **load** data in RDBMS by MR, but you or your team can design your applications to **process** data in RDBMS maybe by using some modules/codes of Sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

- If performance & scalability is your first priority, yes, you have to
  move all your data from RDBMS to HDFS for efficient processing.
- MR jobs process data from in and out of HDFS. After the data is
  processed you can import the data from HDFS by MR or just using HDFS
  apis to other sources.
- No, you cannot use MR for its parallel features while jobs still
  access data from traditional sources. MR jobs splits the input data
  and pass on the it to various maps. With the traditional sources it
  wont be possible.